# Telerik RadDatePicker hiding behind iframe in IE11

Tags: raddatepicker

I have a RadDatePicker that hiding bihind the iframe when pdf is viewed. I tried using z-index but It didn't work. Please advise. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadDataPicker offers an [Overlay property](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_raddatepicker_overlay.html) that you should set to true to fix the problem.